# textview.setvisibility(View.GONE) when text is TextView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set textview visibility from method,

```
if textview.getText() == "Textview"
```

then I want it to be gone

this is the method which returns visibility:

```
private static int checkField(TextView tview){
    int vis;
    if (tview.getText() == "TextView"){
            vis = View.GONE;
            return vis;
    }
    else{
        vis = View.VISIBLE;
        return vis;
    }
}
```

and this is what I use to set visibility:

```
newView.setVisibility(checkField(newView));
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if (tview.getText() == "Textview")
```

Change this line to..

```
  if (tview.getText().toString().equals("Textview"))
```

Comment: this gives the same result the textfields keep showing up

Comment: code is
    private static int checkField(TextView tview){
        int vis;
        if (tview.getText().toString().equals("Textview")){
                vis = View.GONE;
                return vis;
        }
        else{
            vis = View.VISIBLE;
            return vis;
        }
    }
now

Comment: now what? Is it working? Can you pls tell us what do you exactly want to achieve with this code.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use == in string

change

```
if (tview.getText() == "TextView"){
```

to

```
if (tview.getText().equal("TextView")){
```

so all method is:

```
private static int checkField(TextView tview){
    int vis;
if (tview.getText().equal("TextView")){
            vis = View.GONE;
            return vis;
    }
    else{
        vis = View.VISIBLE;
        return vis;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write the method like this:

```
private static int checkField(TextView tview){
    return tview.getText().toString().equals("Textview") ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE
}
```

One way or another if you're not getting the expected result, please try to debug and check if the TextView.getText() is returning "TextView" as value.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to re write your method this way

```
public static void checkField(TextView tview, TextView newView){
    String s = tview.getText().toString();
    if ( s.equals("TextView")){
        newView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return vis;
    } else {
    newView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

You can use the method this way;

```
checkField(tview, newView);
```

Also, why making it private when it is static? private cannot go with static, it is either it is public static or private only

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison for TextView is incorrect, the first problem is you aren’t using the getText().toString() so I believe you would get a difference value than you’re expecting

```
if (tview.getText() == "TextView"){
        vis = View.GONE;
        return vis;
}
```

What you need to do is firstly change it to getText().toString() and then compare if they’re the same string, for that you need to use the compareTo or compareToIgnoreCase methods

```
if (tview.getText().toString().compareTo( "TextView") == 0){
        vis = View.GONE;
        return vis;
}
```

This is from the docs!

compareTo: Compares two strings lexicographically. 
equals: Compares this string to the specified object.

compareTo compares two strings by their characters (at same index) and returns an integer (positive or negative) accordingly. ... 
equals() checks if two objects are the same or not and returns a boolean.

Also you can just do 
     return View.GONE; 
Or
    return View.VISIBLE;
Instead of having to create an object, which is good practice and I believe a bit clearer